# Size of raw response in bytes

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to make a HTTP request and determine the response size in bytes.  I have always used `request` for simple HTTP requests, but I am wondering if I can achieve this using raw?

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', stream=True)
>>> r.raw
```

My only problem is I don't understand what raw returns or how I could count this data-type in bytes?   Is using `request` and raw the right approach?

Comment: Note that the only way to get the size before downloading the entire file is to read the `content-length` header, if it exists.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Just take the `len()` of the content of the response:

```
>>> response = requests.get('https://github.com/')
>>> len(response.content)
51671
```

If you want to keep the streaming, for instance if the content is (too) large you can iterate over chunks of the data and sum their sizes:

```
>>> with requests.get('https://github.com/', stream=True) as response:
...     size = sum(len(chunk) for chunk in response.iter_content(8196))
>>> size
51671
```

Comment: Does this just parse `Content-length` or does it actually measure the full content?  Also, does response.content include HTTP headers?

Comment: That does determine the actual length of the content.  At least the Github front page does not send a `Content-length` header.

Comment: Awesome!  Much appreciated!

Comment: This does not consider the HTML header, as `response.content` is the HTML body in form of a string.

Comment: @BlackJack Is this value is in bytes? Cos I have heard that one character equals 1 byte only if the character set is ASCII latin1. if UTF-8 it can increase to 2 bytes depending on the character.

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Yes the value is in bytes because `response.content` is bytes and not characters. If you want characters use the `response.text` attribute. Of course this only makes sense if the body actually _is_ text. If it's an image for instance, you'll get garbage or a decoding error when accessing the `text` attribute.

Comment: @BlackJack Actually type(r.content) is  <type 'str'> not bytes. Why do you say its bytes?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon you're using python 2, right? Strings (`str`) in python 2 are byte strings. Exec `str is bytes` for fun and profit.

Comment: ya python 2. len() means number of chars in string. so according to my earlier comment, 1 character = 1 byte if its ascii-latin1 only, if not we cant do this right?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon In Python 2 `len()` on a `str` value means number of _bytes_ and `len()` on a `unicode` value means number of _characters_. (Actually number of code points because not everey code point is a character and there are characters consisting of more than one code point.) There is no thing like ”ascii-latin1”. It's either ASCII or Latin1.  Latin1 has ASCII as subset though.

Comment: The OP is using a *streaming response*, accessing `r.content` is going to load all the data into memory first and that is usually **not** what you want when streaming the response.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've added an example with streaming.

Comment: @BlackJack: that's not a good example. Now you consumed all the data from the socket just to get the total size. **At the very least** try to get the `Content-Length` header first. Also see [Progress Bar while download file over http with Requests](//stackoverflow.com/q/37573483)

Comment: The question was how to get the size from a source that _doesn't_ have a `Content-Length` header. If that example isn't good, how would you get the size without consuming the iterable or loading the whole content into memory? Even if I try `Content-Length` first I need to download/consume if there is no Content-Length header.

Comment: How about when compression (e.g. gzip) is applied? Is this answer still right? `r.content` should be decompressed.

Comment: @CarsonIp: no, this answer is not correct. See [Content-length header not the same as when manually calculating it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50825528) for an accurate method.

Comment: It's a bit harsh to call this answer incorrect because compression/decompression is something that usually is transparently done on the fly. The compressed size is rarely interesting because the data isn't stored that way nor can it be used that way if we talk about the content. To get at the content you have to decompress.

Answer (score 7):

`r.raw` is an instance of [urllib3.response.HTTPResponse](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/response.py). We can count the length of response by looking up the response's header `Content-length` or use built-in function `len()`.

Comment: Yes, but `Content-length` is not always provided.

Comment: @ewhitt: If there is no `Content-length` header then you can't know the full length until you have received all data. Accessing `r.content` forces the issue, that reads from the `raw` connection until all data has been read, building up the full document in memory. You may as well not use `stream=True` in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what about `gzip` responses which it automatically decompresses, so `len(r.content)` does not show true response size ... ?

Comment: @madzohan what about those? If you need to know the HTTP body size of the response and there is no content-length header then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825528/content-length-header-not-the-same-as-when-manually-calculating-it

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you) I've finished yesterday with simple urllib's response.read() :)