# Content-length header not the same as when manually calculating it?

Tags: python, python-requests

An answer here ([Size of raw response in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688479/size-of-raw-response-in-bytes)) says :

> Just take the `len()` of the content of the response:
>
> ```
> >>> response = requests.get('https://github.com/')
> >>> len(response.content)
> 51671
> ```

However doing that does not get the accurate content length. For example check out this python code:

```
import sys
import requests

def proccessUrl(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        print("Correct Content Length: "+r.headers['Content-Length'])
        print("bytes of r.text       : "+str(sys.getsizeof(r.text)))
        print("bytes of r.content    : "+str(sys.getsizeof(r.content)))
        print("len r.text            : "+str(len(r.text)))
        print("len r.content         : "+str(len(r.content)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

#this url contains a content-length header, we will use that to see if the content length we calculate is the same.
proccessUrl("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

If we try and manually calculate the content length and compare it to what is in the header, we get an answer that is much larger?

```
Correct Content Length: 51504
bytes of r.text       : 515142
bytes of r.content    : 257623
len r.text            : 257552
len r.content         : 257606
```

Why does `len(r.content)` not return the correct content length? And how can we manually calculate it accurately if the header is missing?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` does **not produce the length of the data**. Instead, it gives you the memory footprint of the internal Python data structures, which is related but far from the same thing. Do not use `sys.getsizeof` in this context. See [What is the difference between len() and sys.getsizeof() methods in python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17574076)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header reflects the body of the response. That's not the same thing as the length of the `text` or `content` attributes, because the response could be *compressed*. `requests` decompresses the response for you.

You'd have to bypass a lot of internal plumbing to get the original, compressed, raw content, and then you have to access some more internals if you want the `response` object to still work correctly. The 'easiest' method is to enable streaming, then reading from the raw socket:

```
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
# read directly from the raw urllib3 connection
raw_content = r.raw.read()
content_length = len(raw_content)
# replace the internal file-object to serve the data again
r.raw._fp = BytesIO(raw_content)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
>>> r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
>>> r.headers['Content-Encoding'] # a compressed response
'gzip'
>>> r.headers['Content-Length']   # the raw response contains 52055 bytes of compressed data
'52055'
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']     # we are served UTF-8 HTML data
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> raw_content = r.raw.read()
>>> len(raw_content)              # the raw content body length
52055
>>> r.raw._fp = BytesIO(raw_content)
>>> len(r.content)    # the decompressed binary content, byte count
258719
>>> len(r.text)       # the Unicode content decoded from UTF-8, character count
258658
```

This reads the full response into memory, so don't use this if you expect large responses! In that case, you could instead use `shutil.copyfileobj()` to copy the data from the `r.raw` file to a [spooled temporary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (which will switch to an on-disk file once a certain size is reached), get the file size of that file, then stuff that file onto `r.raw._fp`.

A function that adds a `Content-Type` header to any request that is missing that header would look like this:

```
import requests
import shutil
import tempfile

def ensure_content_length(
    url, *args, method='GET', session=None, max_size=2**20,  # 1Mb
    **kwargs
):
    kwargs['stream'] = True
    session = session or requests.Session()
    r = session.request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    if 'Content-Length' not in r.headers:
        # stream content into a temporary file so we can get the real size
        spool = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size)
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, spool)
        r.headers['Content-Length'] = str(spool.tell())
        spool.seek(0)
        # replace the original socket with our temporary file
        r.raw._fp.close()
        r.raw._fp = spool
    return r
```

This accepts an existing session, and lets you specify the request method too. Adjust `max_size` as needed for your memory constraints. Demo on `https://github.com`, which lacks a `Content-Length` header:

```
>>> r = ensure_content_length('https://github.com/')
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.headers['Content-Length']
'14490'
>>> len(r.content)
54814
```

Note that if there is no `Content-Encoding` header present or the value for that header is set to `identity`, and the `Content-Length` is available, then just you can rely on `Content-Length` being the full size of the response. That's because then there is obviously no compression applied.

As a side note: you should not use `sys.getsizeof()` if what your are after is the length of a `bytes` or `str` object (the number of bytes or characters in that object). `sys.getsizeof()` gives you the internal memory footprint of a Python object, which covers more than just the number of bytes or characters in that object. See [What is the difference between len() and sys.getsizeof() methods in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574076/what-is-the-difference-between-len-and-sys-getsizeof-methods-in-python)

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense man, thank you. So len of `r.raw.read()` was what i needed. I tried raw earlier but didn't think to use `read()` with it. The link on the difference between `len` and `sys.getsizeof` is also very helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte: the internals of `requests` are such that there is no option to disable the decompression there.