# Not able to do webscraping using beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the first two sections values i.e 1*2 and DOUBLECHANCE sections values using bs4 and requests from this website https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/SubEventDetail?SubEventID=76512106
The code which I written is:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/SubEventDetail?SubEventID=76512106')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='SEItem ng-scope'):
    print(div.text)
```

when I run I am not getting anything please help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is loaded via `JavaScript`, so you have 2 option. or to use `selenium` or to call the `Direct` `API`.

Instead of using `Selenium`, I've called the `API` directly and got the required info.

Further explanation about [XHR & API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044616/using-find-all-function-returns-an-unexpected-result-set/61045691#61045691) < can be found once you click here.

```py
import requests

data = {
    'IDGruppoQuota': '0',
    'IDSottoEvento': '76512106'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, json=data).json()
    count = 0
    for item in r['d']['ClassiQuotaList']:
        count += 1
        print(item['ClasseQuota'], [x['Quota']
                                    for x in item['QuoteList']])
        if count == 2:
            break


main("https://web.bet9ja.com/Controls/ControlsWS.asmx/GetSubEventDetails")
```

Output:

```
1X2 ['3.60', '4.20', '1.87']
Double Chance ['1.83', '1.19', '1.25']
```

Comment: This is great. Ahmed, where should i refer to advance in requests (especially post, like you did)?

Comment: @InfinityTM tracking the `XHR` request, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044616/using-find-all-function-returns-an-unexpected-result-set/61045691#61045691) let me know if it's not clear yet or if you have additional questions

Comment: @InfinityTM within the network tab, once you click on the `XHR` request made. you can see [params](https://imgur.com/MzLsU0e)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I tried this https://bpaste.net/W45Q but getting [] can you please help me out

Comment: @sweety this is the code which I gave to you over the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49079101#49079101) so you can check what I've wrote for you there then.

Comment: Ok I will try @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη
I should get only this 
1X2
1 3.60, X 4.20, 2 1.87

Comment: @sweety i think that my answer is already provided for you the expected output. if you are asking about selenium right now. so you browse the community as it's will be very duplicated question.

Comment: actually your answer getting all the values I want to get only first one and even the 1,x in the section are not coming @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @sweety your question is `I am trying to scrape the first two sections values i.e 1*2 and DOUBLECHANCE sections values` and you have received an answer according to it.

Comment: yes @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη but I should get like this I mentioned
1*2
1 --
DoubleChance
values

Comment: only two I need to get please say that @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη one question where did you find this div.SEOddLnk.ng-binding it is not been showing in html code

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import lxml
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/SubEventDetail?SubEventID=76512106')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('div')
for i in a:
    try:
        print(i['class'])
    except:
        pass
        try:
            sp = i.find_all('div')
            for j in sp:
                print(j['class'])
        except:
            pass
```

This helps you find available classes in the `<div>` tag.
You get nothing when the `class` you give doesn't exist. This happens as many of the sites are dynamically generated and requests can't get them. In these cases, we need to use `selenium`.

Comment: ['divTitle']
['MenuUpdate']
['Terms']
['divBottom']
['Disclaimer']
['CreditLogo']
['divDisclaimer']
['errorLogin']
['modal-backdrop', 'in']
['modal', 'login-error']
['modal-header']
['modal-body']
['col', 'col1']
['form-inline']
['control-group']
['controls']
['control-group']
['controls']
['control-group']
got like this can you help me please @ Infinity TM

Comment: yes that means SEItem ng-scope is not available. you may need to use selenium

Comment: only the classes that came can be extacted by bs4

Comment: now how can I achieve my requirement please help me @Infinity TM

Comment: Use selenium. try searching tutorials for this on google. Try doing with it and if you face a  problem . fell free to ask it in stackoverflow

Comment: @sweety check below answer

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη In `requests.get('https://norvig.com/big.txt', stream=True).headers['Content-length']` it shows `2702205` but on download now in file prop it show `64,88,666`. why is it so?

Comment: that's a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825528/content-length-header-not-the-same-as-when-manually-calculating-it)

Comment: check [that](https://bpaste.net/H4VQ) am online via Phone, so there might be an indention error though.