# Not able to scrape the data by over the div elements using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the every match that is showing in this url https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/OddsToday.aspx?IDSport=590

the every match should be clicked and the data came after clicking that link should be scraped so far I did it for one match

code:

```
# Here using selenium for scraping
# importing necessary modules
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import mysql.connector

# the relevant url
url = 'https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/OddsToday.aspx?IDSport=590'

# the driver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:/Users/SATYA/mysite/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

#elements
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.Event.ng-binding')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
headings= [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SECQ.ng-binding")]
keys = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOdd.g1")]
values = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOddLnk.ng-binding")]

driver.navigate().back();

print(headings,keys,values)

#driver.quit()
```

with this code I am able to scrape one match data after clicking it like that I want to scrape all the matches data by clicking it using selenium the no.of matches may be varying for every day so can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Kindly [edit] your question. and show for us a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to do webscrapping using beautifulsoup and requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139207/not-able-to-do-webscrapping-using-beautifulsoup-and-requests)