# Cant loop the process in certain area - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I'm new to python & getting stuck in this...  My code does some simple stuff, it requests an API endpoint and fetches the user name from the response, and makes a table as input we take **mobile number** .after a successful search it will give us the option to search again. the problem I faced when the invalid mobile number was given as input the code **exit**, the invalid response content-length is **160** so we can easily figure out the invalid request by the content-length, so i store the response content-length in **z3 varibale** . is there any way to check if the content-length is equal to **160** it will print **data not found** and give us chance to search again and send back to this line `num = input ("Enter the mobile number :")` . if content-length is **less than 160** it will fetch the data which I have written in my code
Also the response body for valid & invalid are different
here is a valid response body:
`{"success":true,"data":{"acc_title":"Elon Musk"}}`
And the invalid one :
`{"success":false,"msg":"Sorry, unable to find beneficiary. This is not a customer account","log":""}`

Here is the code :

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table
from rich import print
import requests

p = True

while p == True:

    num = input ("Enter the mobile number :")
    x = num
    data = {'account_type': '11' ,'account_no': x } 

    cookies = {'token': '121212ad2122sdsd2323asas12312'}
    response = requests.post('https://pytest.com/api/user/get_user_info/', data , cookies=cookies) 

    z1 = response.json()
    z2 = response.headers
    z3 = z2["Content-Length"]
    z4 = z1["data"]
    z5 = z4["acc_title"]

    table = Table(title="[+] Found [+]", style="bold")
    table.add_column("Name", justify="right", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
    table.add_row( z5 )
    console = Console()
    console.print(table)
    
    answer = input("want to search again? ")
    if answer == "yes":
            continue
    else:
        exit()
```

**Need your help
Thanks**

Comment: this will help [Size of raw response in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688479/size-of-raw-response-in-bytes)

Comment: for every invalid request content length is fixed  **160**

Comment: what is your question? did you see the link I shared above?

Comment: yes, I saw the link you shared, my question is if  **z3**  variable which is content-length gives us the value of 160 it will  print us  **data not found** and go to  this line again `num = input ("Enter the mobile number :")`

Comment: add this line after finding the `z3` value `if z3 == 160: continue`

Comment: is there any way to go back `num = input ("Enter the mobile number :")` this line if the condition `if z3 == 160:` meets true
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Based on the comments below, I have changed the suggested code, so it checks the json-value assigned to z1 instead. (This contains a success-value, which returns a True or a False.)

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table
from rich import print
import requests

p = True

while p == True:

    num = input("Enter the mobile number :")
    x = num
    data = {'account_type': '11', 'account_no': x}

    cookies = {'token': '121212ad2122sdsd2323asas12312'}
    response = requests.post('https://pytest.com/api/user/get_user_info/', data, cookies=cookies)

    z1 = response.json()
    z2 = response.headers
    if z1['success'] == False:
        print('Data not found.')
    else:
        z4 = z1["data"]
        z5 = z4["acc_title"]

        table = Table(title="[+] Found [+]", style="bold")
        table.add_column("Name", justify="right", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
        table.add_row(z5)
        console = Console()
        console.print(table)

        answer = input("want to search again? ")
        if answer == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            exit()
```

Comment: There is an issue, The response body of a valid one and an invalid is different.
 "data" and "acc_title" are found in a valid response body and there is nothing like in an invalid response body , here is a valid response body:
`{"success":true,"data":{"acc_title":"Elon Musk"}}`
and an invalid :
`{"success":false,"msg":"Sorry, unable to find beneficiary. This is not a customer account","log":""}`

Comment: we need something that sends back to  here `num = input("Enter the mobile number :")`
if the condition **if z3 == 160:**  get true .
my bad maybe I can't elaborate the issue properly

Comment: In the code I suggested it is checked whether z3==160, if that is true it does the print. Because this check happens within your while p == True:, then the code will skip the rest of the code from else: and return to the top of while p == True, in which it starts over. --> This new loop will begin with num = input("Enter the mobile number :")

Comment: when I put an invalid number it show this error 
`File "uuu.py", line 23, in <module>
    z4 = z1["data"]
KeyError: 'data'`

Comment: OK. The reason for that is that the check == 160, is not 160 long and thus the check fails. I am posting an edit to the code, which utilizes the json from your first comment instead.